# Why isn't request.form.get() getting the form input?

Tags: python, forms, flask, jinja2

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2kRV.png)Why do I get all the info from my table instead of only the item selected?

I expected for the {{events.name}} to be retrieved by request.form.get("eventname") so that I can use it to delete the event from the table

Comment: `{{event.name}}` does have only the name of the current event.  But you have `<option value={{events}}>`, which is going to substitute the entire table.  You have confused `event` and `events`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have assigned the option value to the entire list as `<option value="{{events}}">{{event.name}}</option>`. It should be corrected to `<option value="{{event.name}}">{{event.name}}</option>`.